# SQL Job to Pipe Delimited

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am running SQL Job (SQL Server 20208 R2) and I want the results of the script to save to a folder as pipe delimited. Is there any way of doing that by adding to the script? Below is the script. If not can I do it any other way?

```
SELECT Distinct 
    (SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),PatientDemographics.DateofBirth,101),'/','')) as DOB 
    , (SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ScheduleEntry.ScheduleDate,101),'/','')) as DateofService
    , RTRIM(LTRIM(Insurances.EligibilityPayorNumber)) as InsurancePayorCode
    , RTRIM(LTRIM(ContractFacilityProviders.NPI)) as ProviderID
    , RTRIM(LTRIM(PatientInsuranceProfiles.Insurance1PolicyNumber)) as SubscriberInsuranceID
    , RTRIM(LTRIM(PatientInsuranceProfiles.Insurance1PolicyGroupNumber)) as SubscriberGroupNumber
    , RTRIM(LTRIM(PatientDemographics.firstname)) as SubscriberFirstName
    , RTRIM(LTRIM(PatientDemographics.MiddleInitial)) as SubscriberMiddleInitial
    , RTRIM(LTRIM(PatientDemographics.Lastname)) as SubscriberLastName
FROM 
    ScheduleEntry
LEFT JOIN 
    PatientDemographics ON ScheduleEntry.PatientAccount = PatientDemographics.AccountNumber
LEFT JOIN 
    Providers ON ScheduleEntry.ResourceCode = Providers.MedStarProviderIdentifier
LEFT JOIN 
    Facilities ON ScheduleEntry.FacilityCode = Facilities.MedStarFacilityIdentifier
LEFT JOIN 
    AddedResource ON ScheduleEntry.ResourceCode = AddedResource.AddedResourceCode
LEFT JOIN 
    Caregiver ON ScheduleEntry.ResourceCode = Caregiver.CaregiverCode
LEFT JOIN 
    PatientInsuranceProfiles ON ScheduleEntry.PatientAccount = PatientInsuranceProfiles.PatientAccountNumber
LEFT JOIN 
    Insurances ON PatientInsuranceProfiles.Insurance1Mnemonic = Insurances.Mnemonic
LEFT JOIN 
    ContractFacilityProviders ON PatientDemographics.PrimaryPhysician = ContractFacilityProviders.ProviderIdentifier
WHERE 
    ScheduleEntry.ScheduleDate >= getdate() 
    AND ScheduleEntry.ScheduleDate <= getDate() + .50
    AND PatientInsuranceProfiles.Insurance1ContractIdentifier = ContractFacilityProviders.ContractIdentifier
    AND PatientinsuranceProfiles.ActiveFlag = 1
    AND EligibilityPayorNumber > 1
    AND ContractFacilityProviders.NPI > 1
ORDER BY
    SubscriberLastName
```

Comment: NOTE: Your query is not doing what you think it's doing.  By including the right-hand tables of a `LEFT JOIN` in the `WHERE` clause, you are effectively transforming your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @siyaul It's giving me the results that I want though

Comment: Have you researched anything? Tried to Google the solution? Also, people may not want to contribute an answer because it appears by your history that you do not mark responses as accepted answers.

Comment: Getting the answer you want by asking the wrong question is a cause for concern.  It *could* be correct that you need to use an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`, and you're getting the correct results because of the error.  But it could also be giving you the correct results purely out of happenstance, and it could later give you incorrect results.

Comment: @dfundako I have for several weeks now

Comment: @dfundako How do I mark an answer as accepted?

Comment: @JohnMolina Googling 'SQL Job results to file' gives a whole page of options.

Comment: @JohnMolina there will be a check mark just below the voting arrows next to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several ideas

1) Write an SSIS package to export to a flat file, using the pipe as the delimiter.
2) Use BCP as stated already
3) Use sqlcmd to output the result

SSIS will be a nice solution for a SQL job.

I would also echo the previous posters who suggested checking that your aren't negating the effects of your left joins by using the tables in the where clause

Answer (score 1):

You can xp_cmdshell with something like....

```
SELECT DISTINCT
--your columns
INTO ##PIPE_FILE
FROM YourTables
INNER JOIN YourOtherTables


EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 
'bcp "SELECT * FROM ##PIPE_FILE " queryout C:\Folder\Pipes.txt -t"|" -c -T '
```

Comment: Yes as a TSQL Script in an agent job

Answer (score 0):

> **EDIT:**  If you don't have access to xp_cmdshell (many DBAs turn this
>   off)

The following will take the results of **#TempPipe** and dynamically save it as a pipe delimited (with a header -- optional) to your desired location.

Now, you will need the stored procedure listed below, along with the appropriate writes.

```
-- Assumes your query will be saved to #TempPipe
 Select * Into #TempPipe from OD

-- Set Destination File
Declare @Destination varchar(250) = 'C:\Working\Test_Pipe.txt'

-- Construct Field Name and Header from #TempPipe
Declare @Header varchar(max) = '>>>'
Select @Header = @Header +']|['+Name from (select * from tempdb.sys.columns where object_id = object_id('tempdb..#TempPipe') ) A Order by column_id
Select @Header = Replace(@Header,'>>>]|','')+']'

Declare @SelectHead varchar(max) = 'Select Pipe=cast(Replace(Replace('''+@Header+''',''['',''''),'']'','''') as varchar(max)) '
Declare @SelectData varchar(max) = 'Select Pipe=cast(concat('+Replace(@Header,'|',',''|'',')+') as varchar(max)) from #TempPipe '
--If Version<2012  Declare @SelectData varchar(max) = 'Select Pipe=cast(cast('+Replace(@Header,'|',' as varchar(500))+''|''+cast(')+' as varchar(500)) as varchar(max)) from #TempPipe '

Declare @SQL varchar(max) ='
Declare @String varchar(max) = '''';
Select @String = @String + Pipe + char(13)+char(10) From ('+@SelectHead+' Union All '+@SelectData+' ) A

Exec [dbo].[prc-Write-To-File] @String, ''' + @Destination +'''
'
--Select @SQL
Exec(@SQL)
```

The stored procedure to write any string to any file

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO

CREATE Procedure [dbo].[prc-Write-To-File] (@text as Varchar(Max), @Filename Varchar(200)) AS
Begin
    Declare @Object int,@rc int,@FileID Int

    EXEC @rc = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @Object OUT
    EXEC @rc = sp_OAMethod @Object , 'OpenTextFile' , @FileID OUT , @Filename , 2 , 1
    Set @text = Replace(Replace(Replace(@text,'&','&'),'<' ,'<'),'>','>')
    EXEC @rc = sp_OAMethod @FileID , 'WriteLine' , Null , @text
    Exec @rc = [YourDatabaseName].dbo.sp_OADestroy @FileID
    Declare @Append bit
    Select @Append = 0
    If @rc <> 0
    Begin
        Exec @rc = [YourDatabaseName].dbo.sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SaveFile',null,@text ,@Filename,@Append
    End
    Exec @rc = [YourDatabaseName].dbo.sp_OADestroy @Object
End
```

Small sample of the text file generated

```
ODNr|ODID|ODClass|ODTitle|ODLMUsr|ODLMUTC|ODDeleted
0|UNDEF|UNDEF|Undefined|2|Apr  5 2016  1:40PM|0
1|SYSTEM|UNDEF|System|2|Apr  5 2016  1:40PM|0
2|UNDEF|USER|Cappelletti, John|2|Apr 12 2016  7:04PM|0
3|UNDEF|UNDEF|Daily Production Summary|2|Apr 14 2016 12:28PM|0
```